# IF in htaccess. Want to use different include_path for different servers

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I develop websites on my local webserver, the develop server. Whenever development is finished I transfer the website to it's live server. For the develop and the local server some different .htaccess settings are needed, for instance:

```
php_value include_path ".:/Localserver/global/stuff_develop/"
php_value include_path ".:/Liveserver/global/stuff_live/"
```

I would like to have some sort of IF statement in my htaccess that enables it to use the right include_path based on the server it sits on. This makes it possible to transfer the .htaccess file without having to change it to facilitate for the server it is on. Is this possible, and if yes, how would I do this?

I already tried playing around with SetEnvIf which sets a _SERVER variable "local" to value "1" when we're on the local server. Could this be used in htaccess itself for this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As always, first question: do you have full control over the Apache server?

Comment: Then why .htaccess and not a VirtualHost in Apache's main config?

Comment: It's easier to maintain imo. But how would you do it using a VirtualHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried solving this in PHP using ini_set('include_path', ...) ?

E.g. if a page script resides in "/Localserver/site1/pages" resp. in "/Liveserver/site3/pages" something like

```
$basepath=dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
switch ($basepath) {
    case ('/Localserver'): ini_set('include_path',...) ; break;
    case ('/Liveserver'): ini_set('include_path',...) ; break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, useful idea. But I would like to set a condition IN the .htaccess

Comment: I get no suggestions about doing this IN the .htaccess. Accepting this as the only way to do this. It's a workable solution, although not perfect in my opinion. I'll have to put this code in multiple files in our situation, putting it in .htaccess would prevent this.